# How do you seek in VLC 2.0.6 in C#

Tags: c#, vlc, seek, libvlc

I am using a VLC 2.0.6 ActiveX control in a Visual Studio 2012 windows application. I figured out how to load and play a basic video using the following code:

```
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(filename, title, null);
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically seek the video to a certain location. I scowered the internet and found people talking about *shuttle()*, *MoveToPosition()*, *Position*, and more, but none of those methods/properties are available to me. All I can see is *axVLCPlugin21.StartTime*, which is an int, and setting that either before, or after calling *play()* has no affect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're working with LibVLC? Would you be able to give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation here

http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin

one can set the seek position by using

axVLCPlugin21.input.time = 20000; // in milliseconds

There is more information there on getting the total length in milliseconds.

And if it doesn't show up in your auto-generated COM wrapper, ditch it altogether and roll your own. It's not too difficult to make your own inheritor of AxHost and use a "dynamic" (the .NET 4 keyword) OCX object.